# Update sprite position using arrow keys in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I'm trying to make a sprite move when the arrow keys are pressed (just left and right) but nothing is happening. I've been trying to get this to work but I wasn't able to do it. The sprite gets drawn but it doesn't move, it just stays there. Here's the code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.sprites = []
        self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load('Sprites/Player/running1.png'))
        self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load('Sprites/Player/running2.png'))
        self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load('Sprites/Player/running3.png'))
        self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load('Sprites/Player/running4.png'))
        self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load('Sprites/Player/running5.png'))
        self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load('Sprites/Player/running6.png'))
        self.current_sprite = 0
        self.image = self.sprites[self.current_sprite]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = [x,y]
        self.x = self.rect.x
        self.y = self.rect.y
        self.walking = False
        self.vel = 5
    
    def walk(self):
        self.walking = True

    def update(self):
        if self.walking == True:
            self.current_sprite += 1         
            if self.current_sprite >= len(self.sprites):
                self.current_sprite = 0
                self.walking = False
            self.image = self.sprites[self.current_sprite]


sWidth = 800
sHeight = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((sWidth,sHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
background = pygame.image.load('Sprites/Background/bg1.jpg')

allSprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player(300,230)
allSprites.add(player)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
keepGoing = True

while keepGoing:
    clock.tick(20)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            keepGoing = False
```

Now, I want to have it move whenever I hit an arrow key.

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    player.x -= player.vel

elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    player.x += player.vel

else:
    player.walking = False

screen.blit(background, (0,0))
allSprites.draw(background)
allSprites.update()
pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of the player is stored in `self.rect`. The `rect` attribute is used by [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) to draw the *Sprite*. Therefore you must update `player.rect.x` and `player.rect.y` rather than `player.x` and `player.y`. You don't need the attributes `x` and `y` at all:

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    player.rect.x -= player.vel

elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    player.rect.x += player.vel
```